# C++ parallel programming function calls

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I am very new to this Parallel Programming and I am using OpenMP.
I am confused on the following issue.

Say I have this program:

```
void functionX(int x){ 
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    //do some process
}

void functionY(int x, int y){ 
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
       funtionX(j);
    }  
}

void functionZ(int x){ 
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    functionY(i, 5);
}

int main() {
    functionZ(3)
}
```

Now I want to achieve parallel programming on this code. Because *functionZ* calls *functionY* which calls *functionX*, I think that instead of making each function parallel, I should just make *functionZ* parallel therefore each threads in *functionZ* will make their individual calls to *functionY*

This is how my code in functionZ looks.

```
void functionZ(int x){ 
 #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    functionY(i, 5);
}
```

However, I am not sure if what I stated above is correct. Should I make each function parallel separately?

Comment: What you are suggesting makes perfectly sense, each thread can execute a different call to `functionY();` but ONLY if there is no dependency between invocations of `functionY();` which seems to be your case. However you should consider data parallelism other than thread parallelism: the data read in functionX() are efficiently read in this way? Can data read become a bottleneck?

Comment: I am sorry but I thought data parallelism is the thread parallelism. Is it different?

Comment: Thread parallelism refer to the possibility to execute tasks in parallel. You also need to check if the needed data can be parallelized: does one iteration need data produced by the previous iteration? Does the threads need to access a shared memory location with a locking mechanism? Does all of them read from a file? Would be more efficient to replicate that data once per every thread so each of them work in its local copy? These questions are about data parallelism. You should ask yourself these questions or at least to be aware of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me, but if really the limit in number of iterations of the `for` loop inside `functionZ()` is 3, then that will greatly limit the expected scalability of your code. Ideally, you want you parallelisation to be at the outer-most possible level in the code, but with a sufficient work to distribute among threads to ensure a good and balanced use of all the available computing resources.

One solution if indeed your trip count in `functionZ()` is that low would be something like this:

```
void functionY(int x, int y){
  #paragma omp for collapse(2) schedule(auto) 
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
       funtionX(j);
    }  
}

void functionZ(int x){
  #pragma omp parallel 
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    functionY(i, 5);
}
```

You can fiddle with this approach to find the best place for your worksharing, along with the best scheduling, depending on your actual problem.

Comment: Sorry I just wrote 3 as example but actually is a  Image frame thats will be about (640 x 480) iteration. Besides that, as you wrote that #pragma in functionY(,) I wonder how divisions of threads will be handle in functionY. It is exactly same as functionZ.

Comment: The way I wrote it, all threads will execute all the iterations of the loop in `functionZ` independently,  but will distribute the iterations of the two loops in `functionY` among themselves as effectively as possible (according to the run-time library's scheduling decision) when they reach it. Now, if your loop trip in `functionZ` is typically 640, your initial solution is perfectly fine and you can disregard mine.

Comment: Note that `collapse(n)` is OpenMP v3, so may not be available. If the amount of work in each iteration is not constant, then using dynamic scheduling can help to eliminate the long-tail of low CPU utilisation at the end of each outer loop `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)`. I only have OpenMP v2, so I don't know how this interacts with `collapse(n)`, though.

Comment: This video describes how to use openmp for maximised CPU utilisation https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/crash-course-on-multi-threading-with-openmp